# Problema al enviar un audio por WhatsApp desde la carpeta raw

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando mando a `Whatsapp` un audio que está guardado en la carpeta `raw` de mi aplicación, se manda el archivo pero sin formato, es decir, se manda un archivo sin título y sin la extensión.

He comprobado que ese archivo si le pongo manualmente la extensión `.mp3` puedo escucharlo.

Código que estoy utilizando:

```
Intent compartiraudio = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/raw/audio");

compartiraudio.setType("audio/,mp3"); //el tipo es un audio

compartiraudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartiraudio, "Comparte un archivo de audio"));
```

---

Este es el resultado final en `WhatsApp`:

[image: WhatsApp]

¿Como puedo enviarlo como si fuera un audio de `WhatsApp`?

Comment: Posible duplicado [Como mandar audios a Whatsapp/Telegram guardados en la carpeta raw?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/153763/69447), la pregunta se relaciona, considero que debes esperar a que alguien se anime a responder y no postear dos preguntas semejantes

Comment: PASO MI SOLUCION!! ME PASABA LO MISMO QUE A VOS. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206642/compartir-archivos-multimedia-de-la-carpeta-raw-en-las-redes-solucionado

Comment: quita la coma del mp3, en la parte "audio/,mp3", que quede "audio/mp3"

Answer (score 0):

Me volví loco, pero al fin me tropece con la solución en internet y se las comparto!!

cualquier duda chuequean el enlace. http://www.aprendeandroid.com/YAF/default.aspx?g=posts&t=54

```
//Mi boton que al mantener pulsado por un periodo va llamar al metodo compartir

        buttonRep25= (Button)findViewById(button25);
        buttonRep25.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //llamada al metodo donde le damos los valores (int a1 ,String a2)

            compartir(R.raw.futuru_por_pasado,"futuru_por_pasado.mp3");

            return false;
        }

    });



//Metodo Compartir
 public void compartir (int a1 ,String a2)
{
    try {

// Abrimos el recurso y lo metemos en un bufer

        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(a1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
        ins.read(buffer);
        ins.close();

// Grabamos el bufer en un fichero
        String filename = getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File open = new File(getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2);

    final Intent comparte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    comparte.setType("audio/mp3");
    comparte.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(open));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(comparte,"Enviar a..."));

        }
```