# Compartir archivos multimedia de la carpeta Raw en las redes

Tags: android, android-studio, mediaplayer

Nada más que el titulo. 
Mi problema es que no puedo compartir por redes audios almacenados en la carpeta Raw.

Answer (score 0):

Me volví loco, pero al fin me tropece con la solución en internet y se las comparto!!

cualquier duda chuequean el enlace. 
http://www.aprendeandroid.com/YAF/default.aspx?g=posts&t=54

```
//Mi boton que al mantener pulsado por un periodo va llamar al metodo compartir

        buttonRep25= (Button)findViewById(button25);
        buttonRep25.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //llamada al metodo donde le damos los valores (int a1 ,String a2)

            compartir(R.raw.futuru_por_pasado,"futuru_por_pasado.mp3");

            return false;
        }

    });



//Metodo Compartir
 public void compartir (int a1 ,String a2)
{
    try {

// Abrimos el recurso y lo metemos en un bufer

        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(a1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
        ins.read(buffer);
        ins.close();

// Grabamos el bufer en un fichero
        String filename = getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File open = new File(getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2);

    final Intent comparte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    comparte.setType("audio/mp3");
    comparte.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(open));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(comparte,"Enviar a..."));




        }
```